# How to seed data in NestJs & Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I've `shops` and `products` collections in Mongodb.

### Shops Schema

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Shop extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true, index: { unique: true } })
  id: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, index: { unique: true } })
  shop: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  accessToken: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  scope: string;

  @Prop({ type: Date })
  expires: Date;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean })
  isOnline: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  state: string;
}

export const ShopSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Shop);
```

### Products Schema

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Product extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true, index: {unique: true} })
  id: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  title: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  desc: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  price: number

  @Prop({ required: true })
  stock: number

  @Prop({ type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Shop', required: true })
  shopId: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;
}

export const ProductSchema  = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Product);
```

Now I want to seed some dummy data (from json) into `products` collection whenever new `shop` is added. I've done using **Nestjs Command** and it worked perfectly. But I don't want to seed data by using command, so I tried on Nestjs lifecycle event method (which is not a proper way to do). Can anyone recommend me any other method?

I heard we can do using Mongoose hooks. If we can, please anyone explain about it.

Comment: Can you clarify on what kind of data you need to seed?

Comment: Thank you for you concern & sorry for late reply. I've fixed it using Mongoose Hooks.

Comment: @Niroj can you or anyone knows tell how do you do it with mongoose hooks?